# How can I count the foreach loops in the HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have this code:

```
<div class="main">
    <form id="uploadFile" data-bind="attachForm: uploadFile">
        <div id="queue"></div>
        <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple = "true">
        <input type="hidden" id="SESSION" name="SESSION" data-bind="value: session" />
    </form>

    <table class="dataTable" name="details">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-bind="text: MDCode"></th>
                <th data-bind="text: TargetAchieved"></th>
                <th data-bind="text: Month"></th>
                <th data-bind="text: Year"></th>
                <th data-bind="text: MDName"></th>
                <th data-bind="text: Document"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: mainData">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: MDCode"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: targetAchieved"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: month"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: year"></td>        
                <td data-bind="text: MDName"></td>
                <td> Open </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm using `knockoutjs` to bind the values. The problem is that I need to count the foreah loop. The `mainData` is filled by the upload form(on the top). Every attached file is one row in the table. I can not count the `mainData` inside of my viewmodel, because when it's called the`mainData` is empty.
 I also tried:

```
rowCount = $('#details tr').length;
console.log(rowCount);
```

But it always returns 0, because when the viewModel is called there are no rows at all.

Please, help me with this issue. I'm pretty sure that the problem is inside of my logic, or I'm missing something really small, but I'm not able to spot it.

Comment: it should be $('.dataTable tr').length because the dataTable is a class not an identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to change the selector because `details` is not the `id` of the table, but is is the `name` so you need to use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
rowCount = $('table[name="details"] tr').length;
```

Comment: ok, but it's always 0, because when the viewmodel is loaded, there are no rows in the table. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    rowCount = $('table[name="details"] tr').length;
    alert(rowCount);
});
```